# Using R to perform a web query and return URL's

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R, and have never used it for writing a web query before. I was wondering if there were any preexisting packages out there that would fit my needs. I am trying to search for a company and return the URL of their website. I have the company name, address, and phone number. Is there a way to run a program that will check the website against the information I have to confirm it's the correct website?

Comment: Have a look at `RCurl`, that could be a good option for you.

Comment: And `httr`: https://github.com/hadley/httr. It provides a more user friendly wrapper on top of RCurl.

Answer (score 4):

Can't guarantee that this will work every time but definitely use the `RCurl` package

```
library(RCurl)
geturlname <- function(name){
    h = getCurlHandle()
    z <- getURL(paste0("http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=",name), # google i'm feeling lucky
        followlocation=TRUE, curl=h)
    getCurlInfo(h)$effective.url # catch the url redirect
}
geturlname("Apple")
geturlname("Google")
geturlname("Blockbuster")
```

Answer (score 4):

Thomas' function is a little easier to write with httr because it:

- automatically manages handles for you
- automatically follows redirects
- returns an object that represents the results of the request

And here's the function:

```
library(httr)
geturlname <- function(name){
  url <- paste0("http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=", name)
  GET(url)$url
}
geturlname("Apple")
geturlname("Google")
geturlname("Blockbuster")
```